# Cannot build 32bit Mongo DB C++ Driver

Tags: c++, mongodb

I am attempting to compile the Mongo DB C++ Drivers as 32bit libraries. How ever I don't know what switch to use, I have looked every where. I am on an x64 environment so I have to force 32 bit compilation.

The reason why I need 32 bit drivers is because the application I am coding is 32 bit and thus I had to compile Boost as 32 bit too.

If I do manage to compile the driver in 32 bit, will I still be able to connect to a 64 bit Mongo DB???

How do I do compile this thing to 32 bit?

Here's the error from the SCon log:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/zinglish/Projects/CPP/Grepho/libs/boost_1_54_0/dist/lib/libboost_thread.so when searching for -lboost_thread
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/zinglish/Projects/CPP/Grepho/libs/boost_1_54_0/dist/lib/libboost_thread.a when searching for -lboost_thread
```

Basically it won't compile because it's trying to compile as x64 but the boost libs are x86...

Comment: What platform? What problem are you having specifically? Yes, you can use a 32 bit driver to connect to a 64bit MongoDB server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I searched this link: [SConstruct Documention](http://www.scons.org/doc/0.96.96/HTML/scons-user/a3414.html) for Linker and Compiler switch customization and came up with a solution.

I added these to the end of the `Environment` variable in the SConstruct file:

```
CPPFLAGS=["-m32"],
LINKFLAGS=["-m32"]
```

Hopefully that will help someone else in the future